# How to obtain jaccard similarity in matlab

Tags: matlab, similarity

I have a table:

```
   x   y   z 
A  2   0   3   
B  0   3   0    
C  0   0   4    
D  1   4   0
```

I want to calculate the Jaccard similarity in Matlab, between the vectors A, B, C and D.
The formula is :

[image]

In this formula |x| and |y| indicates the number of items which are not zero. For example |A| number of items that is not zero is 2, for |B| and |C| it is 1, and for |D| it is 2.

|x intersect y| indicates the number of common items which are not zero. |A intersect B| is 0. |A intersect D| is 1, because the value of x in both is not zero.

e.g.: jaccard(A,D)= 1/3=0.33

How can I implement this in Matlab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matlab has a built-in function that computes the Jaccard distance: `pdist`.

Here is some code

```
X = rand(2,100);
X(X>0.5) = 1;
X(X<=0.5) = 0;

JD = pdist(X,'jaccard')  % jaccard distance
JI = 1 - JD;             % jaccard index
```

**EDIT**

A calculation that does not require the statistic toolbox

```
a = X(1,:);
b = X(2,:);
JD = 1 - sum(a & b)/sum(a | b)
```

Comment: +1 was going to suggest the same (although it does require the Statistics Toolbox).

Comment: Is it necessarily the case that a,b are logical?

Comment: @Try Hard not necessarily, but `JD = pdist(rand(2,100),'jaccard')` is `1`, kind of non-informative!

Comment: @Magla I don't know much about this function, I'm merely curious because the OP's problem does not appear to be restricted to 0/1...

Comment: @TryHard Normally the Jaccard distance/index is for binary data and OP probably wants to convert to binary judging by their example outputs - although the Matlab implementation will also work with non-binary data as long as the matches are exact - e.g. try running `X = randi(10,[2,100]);` through it.

Comment: @nkjt gotcha... thanks for the clarification (could have looked it up :)) the OP example makes sense now...